# is the header tag <header> responsive?

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrapping

I am trying to put a logo next to my navbar-tabs. I'm able to get it to work when my img and navbar are nested inside a header tag. However my navbar loses its responsive capabilities when nested, but if I don't nest them then when on large screen navbar and logo are located in different corners do to the float attributes. On smaller screen however the navbar gets pushed behind the logo and the navbar acts the way it should as screen gets smaller. Is the `<header>` tag no responsive or is there a better way to get what I want?
I'm using dreamweaver cc15 bootstrap.

here is the code i have now as it works how i want; minus being reponsive.

```
<header>
  <div class="header-wrap">
    <div class="inner">
    <a href="home.html" id="logo">atlanteacademy.com</a>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="tournament.html">TOURNAMENT</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="aboutus.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Here is the CSS code which also helps in making it do what I want.

```
.container header .header-wrap {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 100;
    width:auto;
    height: 150;
}
header .header-wrap .inner {
    width: 936px;
}
.inner{
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.header-wrap .inner #logo {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 155px;
    height: 134px;
    background: url(../images/atlantefc.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    float: left;

}
.header-wrap .inner .nav.nav-tabs {
    width: 781px;
    height: 134px;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: right;
    color: #0810A3;
    font-family: kelly-slab;
    font-style: normal;
    /* [disabled]font-weight: 400; */
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background-color: #FFF;
}



.container .nav.nav-tabs .active a {
    color: #EE0201;
    background-color: #BDBABA;
}
```

Thanks for the help and time.

Comment: You need to look into using `media-queries`. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Not sure if this info is helpful, but <header> is treated as a display: block; by most browsers, according to W3Schools.

Comment: I already have media-queries when I had set up the bootstrap. The css i posted is in my main.css

Comment: To the title question itself: there's no such thing as a "responsive" HTML element. CSS is what makes any piece of HTML responsive. I suggest doing some reading on Bootstrap's site, especially around the [responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I guess you could call divs responsive as they are 100% width by default by having `display: block` while `spans` are not responsive because they are displayed inline. It's still far fetched to call them responsive, but it might be a nice practice to try to build a responsive site without using `CSS` :D